# MySQL/Html encoding

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, encoding, character-encoding

I have some really strange problem. I have a MySQL database and a sample php page (I'm working with CakePHP if this information can help to solve the problem). When I select from the database and print the information on the screen I get something like - "??????". The fields in the database are with collation "utf8_general_ci" like the whole tables and the whole database. The php/html document have "" and there are still "??????" what can I do to solve my problem and view the text in the language I want?

Comment: how about showing us the code you are using to save this to the db...

Comment: Are you viewing the page with the correct encoding in your browser?

Comment: "On the screen"? In the browser? In a terminal window? Somewhere else?

Comment: I've inserted the entries through the phpmyadmin "Insert" option. I also tried with SQL code like this -> INSERT INTO cities VALUES('','София') and the result was the same. I can see this in php my admin but I can't in the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you still adding a HTML charset?

```
<?php echo $html->charset('utf-8'); ?>
```

In a config.php make sure that is properly encoding. In a config/database.php:

```
'encoding' => 'utf8'
```

Or you are using standard latin encoding such as ISO-8859-1:

```
'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1'
```

Comment: I forgot about the "encoding" property in the cakePHP's database config file. Thanks! : )